# How to solve error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip

Maybe it is the issue with the edition of the package? The error goes like this:

```
    Using cached thejoker-1.2.2.tar.gz (130 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated 
    packages.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run 
    successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
╰─> [135 lines of output]
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
  Collecting setuptools_scm
    Using cached setuptools_scm-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
  Collecting extension-helpers
    Using cached extension_helpers-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
  Collecting scipy
    Using cached scipy-1.11.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.12.12-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
  Collecting cython
    Using cached Cython-3.0.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
  Collecting twobody
    Using cached twobody-0.8.3.tar.gz (115 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 
   'done'
   ...
   │ exit code: 1
   ╰─> See above for output.

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've tried pip install --upgrade setuptools but it didn't work. Can someone teach me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please post the full error Traceback, with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to involve installing build dependencies, potentially linked to the 'twobody' package. Sometimes errors like this can stem from conflicts between package versions or system configurations. You might want to try creating a virtual environment for your project and reinstalling the packages. Additionally, ensure your Python environment is up to date and try installing the 'twobody' package separately to see if it throws any specific errors. If this doesn't help, checking the package's documentation or GitHub repository for reported issues could provide insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I try to install 'two body' separately, and the error is :  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twobody
ERROR: Could not build wheels for twobody, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: and WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'